# How to get alert dialog only after disconnect call?

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

In my app i am doing one thing that,when the call is disconnected by caller or receiver,one alert dialog should appear with cellphone number.it all works fine but issue is alert dialog is also appearing when i am getting call,but i only want only after disconnection,i don't know what is mistake i am making following is my code..can any one help?

```
     public class MyCallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

private String incomingNumber;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if  (intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE).equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE)) {
        // This code will execute when the phone has an incoming call

        // get the phone number 

        incomingNumber = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
        Intent i = new Intent(context, Disp_Alert_dialog.class); 
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        i.putExtra("Number", incomingNumber);
        context.startActivity(i);
        Toast.makeText(context, "Call from:" +incomingNumber, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


       /* String incomingNumber = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
        Toast.makeText(context, "Call from:" +incomingNumber, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();*/

    } else if (intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE).equals(
            TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE)
            || intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE).equals(
                    TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK)) {
        // This code will execute when the call is disconnected



    }
}
```

Comment: You need to start your activity in `else..if` condition because that action perform when your phone is disconnected.

Comment: @PiyushGupta sorry i dint get you..sorry for my bad english

Comment: This will be    `Intent i = new Intent(context, Disp_Alert_dialog.class); 
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        i.putExtra("Number", incomingNumber);

        context.startActivity(i);` in `else..if` condition.

Comment: can you give it as answer..

Answer (score 1):

You have written your code in wrong place. This code

```
Intent i = new Intent(context, Disp_Alert_dialog.class);   
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
i.putExtra("Number", incomingNumber); 
context.startActivity(i);
```

will be in `else..if` condition instead of `if` condition.

Comment: You need to write it also in else if condition.

Comment: I think it would still show dialogue box when call is picked up, ie phone goes into `ONHOOK` state.

Comment: also number will only come if call is incoming.

Comment: @PiyushGupta can you tell what is event exactly works well with disconnection only??

Answer (score 1):

You condition is wrong. You are using else block of

```
if (intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE).equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)
```

It will run whenever call state changes to 'Ideal' or 'off hook' (in outgoing call - when dialed and call is disconnected, in incoming call - when call is picked up and call is disconnected).

If you want to show dialogue only while disconnecting call, use

```
if (intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE).equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDEAL)
```

and write code in if block

As for number, you cannot get number that way as it is only valid for ringing state.
A work around would be using a [ContentObserver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/ContentObserver.html%22ContentObserver%22) on CallLog. Its `onChange()` will be called whenever there is a change in call log. You can then take number from call log. But you will need to have a part of your application active for this. Use in a `Service` may be.

**Note-** In some devices message also comes in call log data. So check if last entry in call log in of call type or not before showing your dialogue

[This may help you in using content observer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4422410/how-to-implement-a-contentobserver-for-call-logs)

Comment: and alert dialog open when i am making call.not only disconnect call

Comment: what is the action you are using for your reciver.

Comment: and incomming number only comes when call is incoming, ie `EXTRA_STATE `is `EXTRA_STATE_RINGING` [SEE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER)

Comment: put `intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE)` in log and post here.

I think you have to use `CALL_STATE_IDLE` insted of `EXTRA_STATE_IDEAL`

Comment: I know what you meant. Try what I asked in above step.
And you wont get number while disconnecting call.`EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER` is valid for 'ringing state' only. [Refer to this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER)

Comment: Just remove the incoming number. Its not valid for call state ideal. Please refer  link i have sent you in above comments.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79726/discussion-between-roman-and-rishabh-singh-bisht).

Comment: i follow this tutorial http://www.edumobile.org/android/call-finder-demo-in-android-programming/

Comment: Can you tell what is exact event or method works well with only disconnection

Comment: `onChange()` will run.

Comment: ok but sometimes my incoming call screen disappear..is there any way to solve it?

Comment: tell me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31847086/how-to-attach-jpg-or-png-file-to-gmail-or-facebook